# How to prevent copy/paste of the page URL?

Tags: php

When the user is using my website that I create in offline, the user can copy paste the URL of the `index.php` without signing in into the `login.php`.

First the user must login in this URL:

```
http://localhost/first/login.php
```

but instead of doing that the user can copy paste the url of the homepage my url of the home page is

```
http://localhost/first/index.php
```

This url can copy paste and the user can have full use without  signing in the login form

Please help to prevent this.

Comment: use `session` for authentication users , your method is very very unsecure

Comment: Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information between page requests. Session IDs are normally sent to the browser via session cookies and the ID is used to retrieve existing session data. The absence of an ID or session cookie lets PHP know to create a new session, and generate a new session ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple create a session when the login information is correct.

**login.php**:

```
<?php 
      session_start(); // need this to work with sessions


      if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($username == "diego" && $password == "123456") {
           $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
           $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
           header("Location: index.php"); // forward to index site
        }else {
           return "False username and password!";
      }
    ?>
```

**index.php**:

```
<?php 
  session_start(); // need this to work with sessions

  if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['isLoggedIn'])) {
     // do what you want

  }else {
   header("Location: login.php?error"); // forward to login site
  }
?>
```

This is not the best way and not very secure, but it is very simple!

Comment: Thank you for all of your help ...... thank you very much .... please teach me more .... again thank you..

Comment: No Problem you need to Mark this question as answer so other see the correcf one

Answer (score 0):

your method have high security Risk!
attention this example using `session` in php for authenticate users!
[PHP - Login Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_login_example.htm)

```
 <?php
            $msg = '';

            if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) 
               && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

               if ($_POST['username'] == 'tutorialspoint' && 
                  $_POST['password'] == '1234') {
                  $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
                  $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
                  $_SESSION['username'] = 'tutorialspoint';

                  echo 'You have entered valid use name and password';
               }else {
                  $msg = 'Wrong username or password';
               }
            }
         ?>
```